# Gradle error, error: constant expression required

Tags: java, android, gradle

I built apk with version 8.0 gradle.Error reported in the following code

```java
switch (checkedRadioButtonId) {

                                                        case R.id.radioButtonDate:

                                                            Collections.sort(

                                                                inilistdatalist,

                                                                (s1, s2) ->

                                                            Long.compare(

                                                                s1.getInifile().lastModified(),

                                                                s2.getInifile().lastModified()));

                                                            Collections.sort(

                                                                FilesHandler.rwiniArr,

                                                                (s1, s2) ->

                                                            Long.compare(

                                                                s1.iniFile.lastModified(),

                                                                s2.iniFile.lastModified()));

                                                            break;

                                                        case R.id.radioButtonName:

                                                            Collections.sort(

                                                                inilistdatalist,

                                                                (s1, s2) -> s1.getIniname().compareTo(s2.getIniname()));

                                                            Collections.sort(

                                                                FilesHandler.rwiniArr,

                                                                (s1, s2) ->

                                                            s1.iniFile

                                                                .getName()

                                                                .compareTo(s2.iniFile.getName()));

                                                            break;

                                                        case R.id.radioButtonSize:

                                                            Collections.sort(

                                                                inilistdatalist,

                                                                (s1, s2) ->

                                                            Long.compare(

                                                                s1.getInifile().length(),

                                                                s2.getInifile().length()));

                                                            Collections.sort(

                                                                FilesHandler.rwiniArr,

                                                                (s1, s2) ->

                                                            Long.compare(

                                                                s1.iniFile.length(), s2.iniFile.length()));

                                                            break;

                                                    }
```

Error message:

```
/storage/emulated/0/AndroidIDEProjects/RWTranslater/app/src/main/java/com/eam/shuangx339/modtranslater/Activity/IniListActivity.java:264: error: constant expression required

                                      case R.id.radioButtonDate:

                                               ^

/storage/emulated/0/AndroidIDEProjects/RWTranslater/app/src/main/java/com/eam/shuangx339/modtranslater/Activity/IniListActivity.java:278: error: constant expression required

                                      case R.id.radioButtonName:

                                               ^

/storage/emulated/0/AndroidIDEProjects/RWTranslater/app/src/main/java/com/eam/shuangx339/modtranslater/Activity/IniListActivity.java:290: error: constant expression required

                                      case R.id.radioButtonSize:

                                               ^
```

Let me explain.`radioButtonSize,radioButtonName,radioButtonDate` are my
radiobutton id.They will have unique int values in the R file.The error message says that the case is not followed by a constant expression.I don't understand.I wonder if this is a special effect of gradle 8.0.If so, what reasonable way should I code to respond to the event?

I tried the gradle 7.x version and it seems OK.

Answer (score -1):

Create separate comparator functions for each sorting criteria.

```
 private static final Comparator<DataListItem> DATE_COMPARATOR = (s1, s2) ->
    Long.compare(s1.getInifile().lastModified(), s2.getInifile().lastModified());

private static final Comparator<DataListItem> NAME_COMPARATOR = (s1, s2) ->
    s1.getIniname().compareTo(s2.getIniname());

private static final Comparator<DataListItem> SIZE_COMPARATOR = (s1, s2) ->
    Long.compare(s1.getInifile().length(), s2.getInifile().length());

switch (checkedRadioButtonId) {
case R.id.radioButtonDate:
    Collections.sort(inilistdatalist, DATE_COMPARATOR);
    Collections.sort(FilesHandler.rwiniArr, (s1, s2) ->
        Long.compare(s1.iniFile.lastModified(), s2.iniFile.lastModified()));
    break;

case R.id.radioButtonName:
    Collections.sort(inilistdatalist, NAME_COMPARATOR);
    Collections.sort(FilesHandler.rwiniArr, (s1, s2) ->
        s1.iniFile.getName().compareTo(s2.iniFile.getName()));
    break;

case R.id.radioButtonSize:
    Collections.sort(inilistdatalist, SIZE_COMPARATOR);
    Collections.sort(FilesHandler.rwiniArr, (s1, s2) ->
        Long.compare(s1.iniFile.length(), s2.iniFile.length()));
    break;
```

}

hope this help you.

Comment: I know this can be done, but I want to know why the case is not followed by a constant expression, which is clearly possible in gradle 7.0, but I upgraded to 8.0 and reported an error.

Comment: in java 12, the switch statement only allowed constant case expressions in each case. starting from Java 12 (JEP 361: Switch Expressions), and further enhanced in Java 14 (JEP 361: Switch Expressions (Standard)), switch expressions were introduced, allowing for both constant and non-constant expressions in case labels.  in your code checkedRadioButtonId seems to be an identifier (probably an integer) from the Android resources, and it might not be considered a constant expression by the Java compiler. so you got error

Comment: so you can use better if else statement

Comment: Okay, I get it.Thank you for your answer sincerely